# Does detaching an Entity Framework entity also detach its children?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I pull up an ef entity. For example a transaction amendment

```
                var amendment = _context.TransactionAmendments
                .Include(ta => ta.SourceTransaction)
                    .ThenInclude(ti => ti.Account)
                        .ThenInclude(accnt => accnt.ClientAccount)
                .Include(ta => ta.SourceTransaction)
                    .ThenInclude(ti => ti.Person)
                        .ThenInclude(a => a.Contact)
                .Include(ta => ta.SourceTransaction)
                    .ThenInclude(ti => ti.Client)
                        .ThenInclude(a => a.Holder)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(ta => ta.Id == amendmentId);
```

I then want to pull all the information fresh, so I set the state of `amendment` to detached `_context.Entry(amendment).State = EntityState.Detached;`

Will all the children of `amendment` also be detached so that when I run the above query again everything will be pulled fresh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you detach the parent entity from the context, you'll disable lazy loading of child entities as well. You can use `Include` method to load the required children using `Eager Loading`.

Eager loading is the process whereby a query for one type of entity also loads related entities as part of the query.

As described in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectcontext.detach?view=netframework-4.8):

> - Detach only affects the specific object that is passed to the method.
>     If the object being detached has related objects in the object
>     context, those objects are not detached.
> - Detaching objects does not affect data in the data source.
> - Cascade delete directives and referential constraints are not enforced
>     during a detach operation.

Comment: To be clear, related objects that are being tracked by the same ObjectStateManager, those will not be detached automatically.